# Convert Unicode Characters in Python

Tags: python-2.7, character-encoding, escaping

I have the following text that I am parsing from a CSV:

```
Cold food item held above 41Ã‚Âº F except during necessary preparation.
```

I don't even know what the characters represent. I think it's supposed to say 41 degrees fahrenheit.

How can I convert these characters using Python 2.7?

Comment: Decode and encode with the appropriate charsets until it makes sense.

Comment: How do I know what character set it is?

Comment: Half guesswork, half experience.